# Developing XNA outside of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ide, xna

There are some alternative IDE for developing XNA games?

By example, can I to integrate XNA in #develop?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to do with XNA.

You can use the assemblies outside of VS.  However, the content creation pipeline is pretty much tied directly to MSBuild, so if you want to use it, you'll want to stick with Visual Studio.

However, XNA is designed to work with Visual Studio Express Edition, so it is a no-cost option.

Comment: Doesn't Mono include MSBuild these days? Or at least their own, compatible version?